# Python: how best to combine two regex's into one pattern match?

Tags: python, regex, match

Given a list of email header fields of type *Receive* e.g.:

```
Received: by 10.194.174.73 with SMTP id bq9csp183244wjc;
        Mon, 5 May 2014 17:49:10 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.180.14.233 with SMTP id s9mr18354760wic.53.1399337350112;
        Mon, 05 May 2014 17:49:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from mail-wg0-f52.google.com
Received: by mail-ie0-x247.google.com with SMTP id gx4so163592215ieb.1
        for <myemailaddress@gmail.com>; Mon, 01 Jun 2015 18:34:50 -0700 (PDT)
```

Each field reports the "hop" either by IP address or domain name. I'm looking to build a regex that will take care of both.

The following regex's will extract IP address and (gmail) domain name respectively:

```
\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b
mail.*com
```

What's the most elegant approach to combine two or more patterns in Python? I'll be iterating over a list of **Receive** fields and running the regex against each.

Comment: what are you trying to extract from your input?

Comment: You should also consider supporting ipv6 addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just capture all domains and IPs of the hops you can use regex like this.

In python:

```
import re
pat = r'(?:by|for|from) <?([^\s;>]+)'
print(re.findall(pat, text))
```

->

```
['10.194.174.73', '10.180.14.233', 'mail-wg0-f52.google.com', 'mail-ie0-x247.google.com', 'myemailaddress@gmail.com>']
```

(edit to also capture the email)

Comment: ah. well in that case maybe try something like this: (?:by|for|from) <?([^\s;]+)>

Comment: Omits both the email address and repeated domain in brackets. Perfect. Thing is: prior to running the regex, I have removed "Received: "  from each. So the strings in question all begin thus: "by ...". I've tried simply removing the (?:X-)?Received:  (?:by|from) part, leaving only ([^ \n]+), but the remaining pattern matches returns only 'by'. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and timoh: I should have mentioned that I was looking to disregard email address (in which case, of course, my original 'mail.*com' is insufficient).

Comment: @Pyderman could you update the question with the actual data the regex needs to match? If you use the current unaltered data with '(?:by|from) <?([^\s>]+)' it will match all of the received domains and IP addresses and not the email.

Comment: @timoh hmmm, unable to update my questions for some reason. So basically, the data being searched is what you see in the question, minus "Received: " and "X-Received: ", so we're left with four lines starting thus: "by ...

Comment: @Pyderman the pattern in my previous comment still works without the "Received" parts. Note that all of your lines don't start with "by", one starts with "from" - but you shouldn't need to worry about that if you just use the regexp.

Comment: @timoh if by your previous comment, if you mean (?:by|from) <?([^\s>]+), this returns the 'by ' or 'from ' that precedes each IP address or domain, e.g. 'from mail-ie0-x247.google.com' whereas I'm seeking only the domain/IP itself. Also, for a header like: 'from mail-ie0-x247.google.com (mail-ie0-x247.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4001:c03::247])
        by mx.google.com' it also returns the mx.google.com. I'm only interested in the first domain in the header (again, I should have mentioned this). How would you update the regexp?

Comment: @timoh ok it looks like your very first regex (before you modified it to include email addresses) solves the problem of the second IP/domain per header, but only when 'Received: ' is put back at the start of each line. If I pare it back to : (?:by|from) ([^ \n]+), then we get closer, but obviously we still get 'by ' or 'from ' for each IP. When I pare it back any further, things fall apart. You can find the text to be searched here http://bit.ly/1eQNmze. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using re.findall() then you won't get the by or from -parts as results as that is a non-capturing group. You should only get the IP/host - I didn't modify the output I attached to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an alternation?

```
patterns = [r"\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b", r"mail.*com"]
pattern = "|".join(patterns)  # pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|...

re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Yields

```
['10.194.174.73',
 '10.180.14.233',
 'mail-wg0-f52.google.com',
 'mail-ie0-x247.google.com',
 'mailaddress@gmail.com']
```

Comment: Nice. I'm trying to omit email address. Changing r"mail.*.com" to to r'\smail.*com' would suffice, except (I didn't mention this) some of the headers contain the domain followed by the domain again in brackets. e.g. Received: from mail-ie0-x247.google.com (mail-ie0-x247.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4001:c03::247]), and your pattern matches both. How do we take care of both cases (omiting the email address and the repeated domain per line)?